# HTML - Flexbox element alignment in center independently of other elements while maintain its padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox designed page which puts buttons to edges of the page.

All buttons are in place if I have buttons everywhere:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear:both;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <div class="button begin">1</div>
    <div class="button middle">2</div>
    <div class="button end">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <div class="button begin">4</div>
    <div class="button middle">5</div>
    <div class="button end">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="button begin">7</div>
    <div class="button middle">8</div>
    <div class="button end">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <div class="button begin">10</div>
    <div class="button middle">11</div>
    <div class="button end">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, this above code is good, and works like I want. Boxes 2,5,8,11 are all in the middle.

However if I don't need some boxes (like 1,4,10) I still want 2,5,8,11 in the middle.
Now of course they are not in the middle anymore:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear:both;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <!--<div class="button begin">1</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">2</div>
    <div class="button end">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <!--<div class="button begin">4</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">5</div>
    <div class="button end">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="button begin">7</div>
    <div class="button middle">8</div>
    <div class="button end">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <!--<div class="button begin">10</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">11</div>
    <div class="button end">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I can add `flex: 1;` to buttons to have some control over this, but in this case I would lose their paddings (which is important as they are buttons).

Is there any way with flexbox to have 2,5,8 and 11 in the middle all the time, independently of other elements before and after them?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using CSS Grid?

Comment: No reason, I started with flex, and it's getting more and more complicated but this won't be any more complex than now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin:auto` on the middle element in addition to `space-between`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear:both;
  display:flex;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.middle {
 margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <!--<div class="button begin">1</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">2</div>
    <div class="button end">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <!--<div class="button begin">4</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">5</div>
    <div class="button end">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="button begin">7</div>
    <div class="button middle">8</div>
    <div class="button end">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <!--<div class="button begin">10</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">11</div>
    <div class="button end">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a perfect centring you can rectify using some translation like below since the different cases are known:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.middle {
  margin: auto;
}

.tray-top .middle:first-child,
.tray-bottom .middle:first-child {
  transform: translateX(50%)
}

.tray-top .middle:last-child,
.tray-bottom .middle:last-child {
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.tray-left .middle:first-child,
.tray-right .middle:first-child {
  transform: translateY(50%)
}

.tray-left .middle:last-child,
.tray-right .middle:last-child {
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.tray .middle:first-child:last-child {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <!--<div class="button begin">1</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">2</div>
    <div class="button end">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <!--<div class="button begin">4</div>-->
    <div class="button middle">5</div>
    <div class="button end">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="button begin">7</div>
    <div class="button middle">8</div>
    <!--<div class="button end">9</div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <div class="button begin">10</div>
    <div class="button middle">11</div>
    <!--<div class="button end">12</div>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good. one question: what is `.tray .middle:first-child:last-child` for?

Comment: @Daniel when the middle element is alone (first and last at the same time) we don't do any translation

Comment: one more question: if I remove Box2, Box3 will float to left. How can I force Box3 to stay right? (Box2 can be there and can be removed)

Comment: @Daniel add `.tray .end:first-child:last-child {margin-left:auto;margin-top:auto}`

Comment: @Daniel also `.tray .begin:first-child:last-child {margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:auto}`

Comment: One more thing: `:first-child:last-child` selector doesn't work if the child is there but has `display: none`. Is there a way to hide a child while still keep the selector working?

Comment: @Daniel with dispaly:none, the whole code won't work. It would be tricky in this case and we will need another idea

Comment: display:none is fixed, I'm just removing the unnecessary items. However, is there any cool workaround for putting more boxes either as `button begin` (two 10s) or as `button end` to the end (two 12s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce wrapper elements for positioning and place your buttons within:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85%;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 236px;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top,
.tray-bottom {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  clear:both;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.tray-left,
.tray-right {
  width: 48px;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
  float: left;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.tray-right {
  float: right;
}

.button {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.flex-positioning-wrapper { display: inline-block; flex-basis: calc(100% / 3); display: flex; }
.flex-positioning-wrapper .begin { margin-bottom: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.flex-positioning-wrapper .middle { margin: auto; }
.flex-positioning-wrapper .end { margin-top: auto; margin-left: auto; }
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><!--<div class="button begin">1</div>--></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button middle">2</div></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button end">3</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><!--<div class="button begin">4</div>--></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button middle">5</div></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button end">6</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button begin">7</div></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button middle">8</div></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button end">9</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><!--<div class="button begin">10</div>--></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button middle">11</div></div>
    <div class="flex-positioning-wrapper"><div class="button end">12</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: The current setup makes `.tray-left` and `.tray-right` overflow if `#root` is too small - I added `min-height`, but you may have to look for other options if this does not fit your use case.

Note2: My personal recommendation for this layout is to use [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) instead of flexbox,